# clearing a mapItemsControl.Itemtemplate WP7 Maps

Tags: c#, .net, bing-maps, itemscontrol, windows-phone

hi im recurringly updating this map and i noticed its acumulating items rather than just refreshing all items for example

Im assing items to it by mapz.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.LocationItems;
how do i clear the existing items in mapz before this ?

```
  <my:Map x:Name="myMap" Height="480" Width="444" CredentialsProvider="NON YE BIZ" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" Margin="5,0,10,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                    <my:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapz" ItemsSource="{Binding LocationItems}" Width="450">
                        <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <my:Pushpin Name="MyPushPin" Location="{Binding Target_Coordinate}" Content="{Binding Target_NickName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl>
                </my:Map>
```

Comment: Can you please show yoiur code that adds / removes items? what is the type of collection you are binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `LocationItems.Clear()`. If LocationItems is a ObservableCollection, the map with clear off the already rendered items.

No reason at all to access the UI directly when using data bindings.

Answer (score 2):

The `ItemTemplate` defines the look-and-feel and general behavior of a control - it is not the control itself. Therefore, you have to look at the collection itself, and not the template. To clear the existing `ItemCollection`, you need this:

```
mapz.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: You can't use Items for editing if you use ItemsSource (only for read). This code throws exception.